# Shuffle large a scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am having trouble dealing with large matrix. The story is this:

- I have a large matrix (row x col up to 20 million x 20 million).
- Since the matrix has sparse rows, I am using scipy sparse csr matrix to store the matrix.
- In my main algorithm, there is a part that I need to randomly sample a set of rows from this matrix (say 1000 rows).
- If the number of column is too large, I cannot extract all the rows at once as

  ```
  # get a random batch of size b
  index = random.sample(range(n), b)
  X_batch = X[index]
  ```
- My current solution is to extract by batch and do calculation based on that:

  ```
  # get a random batch of size b
  index = random.sample(range(n), b)

  # calculate number of batches
  total_mem_batch = 1e9 # a large number represent the total available memory

  batch_size = int(total_mem_batch // nnzX) # nnz is average number of nonzero per row
  num_batches = math.ceil(b / batch_size)
  result = np.zeros(d)

  for j in range(num_batches): 
      # calculate start/end indices for each batch
      startIdx = batch_size*j
      endIdx = np.minimum(batch_size*(j+1), b)

      batch_X = X[index[startIdx:endIdx],:]
      batch_Y = Y[index[startIdx:endIdx]]
      batch_bias = bias[index[startIdx:endIdx]]

      # do main operation
      result += ...
  ```

Now the bottle neck is at the retrieval of a set of rows of the matrix. Since the index array is shuffled, it can be considered asrandom access to the row of the input matrix X. Therefore, it is much slower than the sequential read.

My question is: is there a way to improve this by either

- shuffle the input matrix once in a while (the order of row does not really matter so it can be shuffled in place) so we can read the element sequentially later, or
- is there a faster way to randomly access row of a large matrix?

Thank you for reading my post.

Best,

Comment: Keep in mind that most sparse indexing is done with matrix multiplication.  It constructs some sort of sparse 'extractor' matrix, and multiplies that and the source matrix to produce a new matrix.  Some operations like slicing might construct the `csr` attributes for the new matrix directly from the originals.  Sparse matrices don't produce `views` (except for a limited `lil` case).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand the point that the output is the product of the masked matrix with the data. However, I am still confused of how to adjust that masked matrix and the corresponding data row at once. Can you elaborate more about this?